# Shiny R app to create cumulative distribution

Tags: r, shiny, probability, distribution

I want to create a simple R shiny app that would let a person choose few things :
a) How many years (trials) we want to test?
b) What we want to test (b.1 - GDP,b.2 - Life Expectancy,b.3 - Happiness)
c) According to the chosen b) variable, I would like to take different probability functions. 
For example, if Life expectancy is chosen, p(x)=(80-x)*0.0025+0.02, and then I would like to have a cumulative distribution graph shown. I took code from google, tried updating it but it didn't work so i would appreciate your help..

```
      library(shiny)

      # Define UI for application that draws a probability plot
      shinyUI(fluidPage(

      # Application title
      titlePanel("Cumulative Binomial Probability Plot"),

     # Sidebar with a slider input for value of lambda
     sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
     sliderInput("lambda",
              "age you want to reach",
              min = 75,
              max = 100,
              value = 1)
     ),

     # Show a plot of the generated probability plot
     mainPanel(
     plotOutput("ProbPlot")
     )
     )
     ))

     # SERVER
     library(shiny)
     library(ggplot2)
     library(scales)

     # Shiny Application
     shinyServer(function(input, output) {

     # Reactive expressions
     output$ProbPlot <- renderPlot({

     # generate lambda based on input$lambda from ui.R
     l=0:1
     lambda <- seq(min(l), max(l), length.out = input$lambda)
     probability=(80-lambda)*0.0025+0.02
     # generate trials based on lambda value
     powers=0.00025
     muCalculation <- function(lambda, powers) {(80-lambda)*powers+0.002}
     probability_at_lambda <- sapply(input$lambda, muCalculation, seq(75, 100, 1))

     # draw the probability
     par(bg = '#191661', fg = '#ffffff', col.main = '#ffffff', col.lab = '#ffffff', col.axis = 
     '#ffffff')
      plot(probability_at_lambda,type="o",col="#b1aef4", xlab="N", ylab="Probability", 
      xlim=c(75, 100), ylim=c(0.0, 1.0), pch=19)
      title(main="Cumulative Binomial Probability")
       })

       })
```

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a useful description of your issue. Please be as specific as possible in describing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you want to do. But the R stats package has an empirical cumulative distribution function ecdf which you can plot. See the help ?ecdf to get details on how it works.  E.g,

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
xcdf <- ecdf(x)
plot(xcdf)
```

Comment: Hello, what i want to do - person inputs a number of life expectancy that he wants to reach and he inputs in how many years he would like to reach that. And I would like R shiny to show the probability of this, with binomial probability calculation and then show a graph of cumulative distribution, throughout the years person chose. for success of each age, I need to calculate probability of success with this formula -> p(x)=(80-x)*0.0025+0.02, (where x is the age person chooses)

Comment: I still don't understand your question.  Are you saying that you want calculate the conditional probability that a person will live to age x given his current age?  E.g., P(x = to 80 | age = 50 now).  Then you would need to know those conditional probabilities.

Comment: E.g, I want to know what is the probability than in 10 years (10 tries for binomial calculation) we will have average age of 80, if a possibility that we will have it next year is 0.02. If we want to test average age of 79, then possibility of having it next year is p(79)=(80-79)*0.00025+0.02=0.02025. So I want to have R shiny app which asks, what age you want to calculate probability for (70-100) and in how many years we would like to test this (n up to 100 years) and then probability of success for binomial will be p(age person puts in)= (80-age)*0.00025+0.002. And then CDF graph.